# Setting up openvpn connection on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set up an openvpn connection on my Ubuntu Phone and I am getting frustrated. I am far from being an expert on vpn connections and so I am having a hard time setting the right things in the vpn-editor on the phone since I only have a .ovpn file from airvpn. I copied everything in between the "ta" tag into ta.key, everything in between "ca" into ca.crt, everything in between "cert" into client.crt and everything in between "key" tags into klient.key. 
The header of my .ovpn file looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote europe.vpn.airdns.org 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo no
route-delay 5
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 5
```

From there I tried to do the settings in the vpn-editor as follows:

[vpn-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGzPT.png)

But it is just not working saying it failed to establish a connection. 
Thanks for the help!!